# bash_profile multiple line alias

Tags: bash, macos

I'd like to run a command called "showfiles" which would run the command "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE" and "killall Finder" How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this...

**Option 1:**
Put a script in your ~/bin directory

```
echo "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE" > ~/bin/showfiles
echo "killall Finder" >> ~/bin/showfiles
chmod +x ~/bin/showfiles
```

**Option 2:**
Create an alias with AND to join the commands together:

```
alias showfiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE && killall Finder'
```

Note: this will only run the second command if the first is successful.

Comment: I tried option 2, but OS X doesn't like the "&&" I don't really want to create a script, so is there another way to create an alias?? I'll create a script if I have to but...

Comment: Option 2 did work for me, I tried it again and I had a space between the showfiles= and the first '. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why the `&&` option @gahooa suggested wouldn't work, but there is yet another option: create a shell function:

```
showfiles() {
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
    killall Finder
}
```

Comment: This is awesome!  It essentially lets you create multi-line aliases (not just multi-command) which make reading them so much more clear.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Put both the statements into a file, one in each line and save the file as showfiles
2. Run `chmod 755 showfiles`.
3. To execute the file run `./showfiles`

If you don't want to do ./ everytime, then place showfiles into any directory in PATH (which you can see by executing `echo $PATH`).